# overlay keyboard for input box in a web control in bada SDK?

Tags: bada

Is there anyway i can have an overlay keyboard for input box in a web control?

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen that yet in any app, except the browser. The web control has some limitations like kinetic scrolling missing and the thing your question targets.

Comment: can i atleast have the type of keyboard launched.... for example for in iPhone web input boxes named with "zip" launches a numeric keypad??

Comment: Yes, you can do that, see the [api documentation](http://static.bada.com/contents/docs/resources_0818/com.osp.apireference.help/classOsp_1_1Ui_1_1Controls_1_1Keypad.html#abe76dcbfc90783c945d6bf51baa30b1) Pass KEYPAD_MODE_NUMERIC as KeypadInputModeCategory  in the Construct()-Method